# How to get the value of encoded data in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, ascii

I would like to know how to get the value from encoded data in Ruby.

In the sample below the value I would like to store in a variable is *FTUV-38VO-FP*. The **puts** method returns the value correctly:

**Ruby Console**

```
(byebug) row[0]
"\u0000F\u0000T\u0000U\u0000V\u0000-\u00003\u00008\u0000V\u0000O\u0000-\u0000F\u0000P\u0000"
(byebug) row[0].encoding
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
(byebug) puts row[0]
FTUV-38VO-FP
nil
```

**Code**

```
  def self.import_csv(hd_wix_event_order_csv_upload_id)
    csv_object = HdWixEventOrderCsvUpload.find(hd_wix_event_order_csv_upload_id)
    CSV.parse(open(csv_object.csv_file.url,"r"), { :col_sep => "\t", :headers => :first_row}).each_with_index do |row,index|
      puts "INDEX" + index.to_s
      puts row
      byebug
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: Your string contains a lot of unusual null characters. You could delete them via `row[0].delete("\0")` but I guess that your CSV is not UTF-8, but some UTF-16 variant. So the _actual_ fix would be opening the CSV with the correct encoding.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan ! It works when using: open(csv_object.csv_file.url,"rb:UTF-16LE")

Comment: Tip: Since Ruby 1.8 is ancient history, use the Ruby 1.9+ Hash syntax: `col_sep: "\t", ...`. Further, you can omit the Hash parens `{ ... }` on "keyword-arguments" at the end of a method call, so this could be `CSV.parse(open(...), col_sep: "\t", headers: :first_row)`

Comment: This looks very much like UTF-16 and not UTF-8. Do you have access to the `file` tool? If so, what does it think? Since the NUL byte is not printable in you coincidentally won't see them in the output, but they might still be present. It's worth nothing that on Windows many, if not most programs use UTF-16 by default.